# When were differing hemispheric seasons first understood?

Tags: science, colonial-america, spanish-empire, 15th-century, 16th-century

When did people - scientists or philosophers - first realise/discover/understand that the seasons in the southern hemisphere were the opposite to those in the northern hemisphere?

Additionally, when and how did they realise that times were different from east to west.

Comment: I'm not sure that the selected tags make sense in respect of the main question.

Comment: It was Iberian navigators who were the first to explore the southern hemisphere during the 15th century and into the 16th century and who would have first become aware of the differences. Perhaps, however, it was postulated before this.

Comment: `It was Iberian navigators who were the first to explore the southern hemisphere during the 15th century`. No. There are some accounts about a Phoneician expedition around Africa, and there is a well documented Islamic presence in Swahili coast (as far South as Mozambique) from the 9th Century. And the Chinese Treasury Fleets probably crossed the Equator (although I am not sure if they crossed the Tropic of Capricorn). And all that just without an extensive search; I would not discard other (and earlier contacts).

Comment: "It was Iberian navigators who were the first to explore the southern hemisphere..." I would say that the people **living at the southern hemisphere** when European explorers arrived would have a stronger claim for the "the first to explore sourthern hemisphere" people than the European explorers.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I'm interested to find out when the notion of opposite seasons became understood between the hemispheres, ie indicative records of that.

Comment: And just to clarify following SJuan's helpful comments I am speaking of the highly differentiated seasons of summer and winter found most clearly well north and south of the equator and to eg such tropical seasons as "rainy" or "typhoon" etc nor to differences in climate between alpine and coastal eg. This therefore most closely relates to the European explorations to the further south such as southern Africa, southern South America and the southern Oceania, ie Australia and New Zealand eg. Hence the tags spanish-empire, 15th and 16th centuries. For the time question, being east-wesr in nature

Comment: the tag colonial-america would seem most relevant along with teh others.

Comment: Sorry, should be "...and NOT to eg such tropical sesaonas as...." above.